# File Svg not render, but chrome begin download IIS server

Tags: javascript, iis, svg

When I open the page the svg image is not rendered. The browser begins to download the svg image and returns this message on the console: 
**"Resource interpreted the Transferred Document but with MIME type application / octet-stream"** 
I'm using an IIS server and have added the MIME-TYPE:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
</staticContent>
```

in my html:

```
<object id="imgSvg" data="map.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

but not resolve. :(

Comment: I would check that the server actually *is* returning that mime type.  You should be able to see by going to the "Network" tab in your browser tools (or Firebug).